# Simple Remix Fail

Tags: remix, vyper

has anybody any idea why the following code cannot be compiled on REMIX with the VYPER COMPILER?

```
@public
@constant

def hello() -> string[100]:
    return "hello world"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I can see.

Vyper doesn't have a `@public` function decorator, nor a `@constant` function decorator.

See the [Decorators Reference](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/control-structures.html?highlight=external#decorators-reference).

The `String` type must be capitalised. (Capital `S`.)

This compiles:

```
@external
@pure
def hello() -> String[100]:
    return "hello world"
```